# Adding specific locations to shp map

Tags: r

I am creating a map on R with the following commands:

```
map_and_data <- inner_join(mapshape, mapdata) // where mapshape is the shp file and mapdata contains the data
ggplot(map_and_data) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill=covidcases))+
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "red4", name = "COVID-19 cases")+
  theme_classic())
```

This produces a normal map by region showing the amount of COVID-19 cases. Then, I have an excel file with a list of the largest 20 cities and their coordenates, and I want to add to the map a point for each one of these cities. How can I overlay a point for the locations of these cities to the original map?

My dataset (previously shp) called map_data looks as follows:

| region_code | geometry |
| --- | --- |
| 080018 | (((410315.5 4598889, 410888.8 4598870~ |
| 080039 | (((384322.7 4625199, 384343.6 4625174~ |

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please provide data to recreate the problem.

Comment: Just add `geom_point` to your plot

Comment: Thank you! I have added two lines of data so that the question is more clear. I have tried using geom_point and it seems to work well, however I believe the problem is with the data itself. Upon closer inspection, it seems like the coordenates under "geometry" from the shp file are wrong. They draw the shape of the map properly but when I want to add the cities (e.g. coordenates 41,25095 / 1,29863) they appear outside of the map, very far away. Is this a common issue? Is there a way to ammend the coordenates to the right ones?

Answer (score 0):

Your city coordinates are in a different coordinate system than the polygons in you shape file. You can sf::st_transform() them into the target [CRS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_reference_system) after reading them.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).